# Element not found in the cache - perhaps the page has changed since it was looked up Command duration or timeout: 9 milliseconds

Tags: java, selenium, xpath

I am new to Selenium WebDriver and using java for the same. On one of the test sites, i am encountering this error. The element is drop down box, and its is 4th Element I am trying to identify on this particular form. First three elements are successfully identified and can be operated, then this error occurs. I have tried Explicit, implicit waits, also tried finding the element again, but not working. Following is the code:

```
wd.manage().deleteAllCookies();

WebDriverWait wait5 = new WebDriverWait(wd, 5);
wait5.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//*[@id='cc_type']")));

WebElement CCType = wd.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='cc_type']"));
Select clickCCType = new Select(CCType); 
clickRoomNos.selectByValue("AMEX");
```

Comment: use `clickRoomNos.selectByVisibleText("AMEX");` instead maybe

Comment: Also, The error occurs even the first time it is run, and not in loop.

Comment: Actually problem solved, I was identifying the different object and using different object to send the values. Now it works fine. Thank you so much Sing31:) The correct code is WebElement CCExpiryMonth1 = wd.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='cc_exp_year']"));
   
   
   Select clickCCExpiryMonth1 = new Select(CCExpiryMonth1); 
   clickCCExpiryMonth1.selectByValue("2018");

Comment: You may post an answer now.